# press Enter in td then pressing tab key

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="UniDataInt">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="uniResult">
        <td contenteditable="true" onfocus="showEdit(this);" class="highlight-border">hello</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onfocus="showEdit(this);" class="highlight-border">hello1</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onfocus="showEdit(this);" class="highlight-border">hello</td>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my Jquery code:

```
$('#UniDataInt').on('keyup', 'td', function() {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        return e.keyCode = 9;
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do when the user presses enter

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#UniDataInt').on('keydown', 'td', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).next().focus();
        }
}); });
```

Comment: Thanks , Its amazing